# PHP Session Breaks between pages

Tags: php, authentication, session

When try to login to Admin Panel session created. But Can't Login to Admin Dashboard. Session Breaks. What's the problem ?

```
<?php
session_start();
require('connection.inc.php');
require('functions.inc.php');
$msg='';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=get_safe_value($con,$_POST['username']);
    $password=get_safe_value($con,$_POST['password']);
    $sql="select * from adminlogin where username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($res);
    if($count>0){
        $_SESSION['ADMIN_LOGIN']='yes';
        $_SESSION['ADMIN_USERNAME']=$username;
        header('location:category_master.php');
        exit();
    }else{
        $msg="Please enter correct login details";  
    }
}
?>
```

I tried Session auto start, Output Buffering, Session save path and everything I could do. I clearly see that session file created in tmp folder but session breaks. Though in php.ini file I mentioned session save path "/tmp". What are the possible reasons. Please help me.

Comment: Your code is likely vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Instead of building queries with string concatenation, always use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: What does "session breaks" mean? Is the client getting the session cookie?

Comment: I'll password_hash() it later. This is not my problem. My problem is session breaks.

Comment: When redirecting to another pages session does not exist.

Comment: Post the code for the other page.

Comment: Check your log for `Headers already sent` warnings. That can cause problems for sessions.

Comment: @barmar What are the problems behind Headers already sent issue ? though Admin login worked for 10days, Its working before

Comment: Sessions work by setting a cookie. If it gets that error when trying to set the cookie, the session won't work properly.

Comment: I get cookie in browser.

Comment: In XAMPP server it also perfectly fine but in live server It does no work after 10days .Could it be a PHP Version issue ?